# EF add a FK that is already defined

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I had a problem with Code first and the generated sql database.

Is an application about bulls and cows

Here are my classes:

```
public class Animal : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int? DeathId { get; set; }
    public virtual Death Death { get; set; }

    public virtual int? SellId { get; set; }
    public virtual Sell Sell { get; set; }
}

public class Death : Event
{
    public virtual int AnimalId { get; set; }
    public virtual Animal Animal { get; set; }
}

public class Sell : Event
{
    public virtual int AnimalId { get; set; }
    public virtual Animal Animal { get; set; }
}
```

which generates this sql script:

```
create table [dbo].[Animal] (
    [Id] [int] not null identity,
    [DeathId] [int] null,
    [SellId] [int] null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
create table [dbo].[Death] (
    [Id] [int] not null,
    [AnimalId] [int] not null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
create table [dbo].[Sell] (
    [Id] [int] not null,
    [AnimalId] [int] not null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
```

All normal, but the problem is with these classes:

```
public class Servicie : Event
{
    public virtual int MaleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Male Male { get; set; }

    public virtual int FemaleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Female Female { get; set; }

    public virtual int? ChildbirthId { get; set; }
    public virtual Childbirth Childbirth { get; set; }
}

public class Childbirth : Event
{
    public virtual int ServicieId { get; set; }
    public virtual Servicie Servicie { get; set; }

    public virtual int FemaleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Female Female { get; set; }
}
```

Those classes generate this Sql script:

```
create table [dbo].[Service] (
    [Id] [int] not null,
    [MaleId] [int] not null,
    [FemaleId] [int] not null,
    [ChildbirthId] [int] null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
create table [dbo].[Parto] (
    [Id] [int] not null,
    [Servicie_Id] [int] not null,
    [ServicieId] [int] not null,
    [FemaleId] [int] not null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
```

As you can see, there is "ServicieId" and "Servicie_Id", the last one, auto added.

All are 1 to 0..1 relationships and I don't see any difference, can someone help me?

Comment: Please simplify and translate your code sample. I can't really tell but I can make a good guess that most of it isn't relevant to your question. (Like all the code for the entities that work as you want.)

Comment: Translated! Tell me if you understand more now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - Added entire test app:

When I used this model (simplied version of yours).  I had to add a Required annotation so EF knew which was the principal and which was the dependant end, it got confused.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CFExamples2
{
    public class Servicio 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int? PartoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Parto Parto { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int ServicioId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual Servicio Servicio { get; set; }
    }


    public class Model : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Servicio> Servicios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Parto> Partos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

It produced this:

[image]

Comment: I tried that and get this:

Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Servicio_Parto_Target' in relationship 'Servicio_Parto'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *Role must be *

Comment: Searching in internet, I found this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx). Looks like EF don't fully support one to one relationship with foreign keys

Comment: Oh i didn't realize it's a 1:1 - yeah you can't have a FK, why dont you just have it share the PK (the only real way EF can do it)

Comment: I will try that, but the million dollar question is why it work with "Animal", "Muerte" and "Venta" and not with "Servicio" and "Parto"? if all are 1 - 0..1 relationships

Comment: I think Visual Studio want make me crazy! I can't get it work, can you please share with me that sample project?

Comment: I've put the entire test app there - it's just a fast console app

Comment: Thank you! Your example works, but when I added the heritage from Evento, Servicio_Id reappeared, and only one table with all fields was generated.

I'll try modifying the model to make it work right.

Thank you very much for your help! I can't up vote you because I need a reputation of 15 and I'm new here.

Comment: You should be able to mark as answer!  Visit the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) scroll down to 'How do I ask a question here?'  and it will show you